# Date-Time on x-axis of ZingChart

Tags: datetime, zingchart

I want to plot date-time vs an integer. I tried Date(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds) but it is not supporting it. So is it possible to plot date-time on x-axis by using zingChart?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For displaying dates, you can use the `transform` attribute on your `scale-x`. It allows you to format your Unix timestamp however you want. Here's an example.

```
"scale-x":{
  "transform":{
    "type":"date",
    "all":"%d %M, %h:%i %A"
  }
}
```

You can see the [rendered chart here](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/RW6YE7DC)

[Here's a link to the docs](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/scale-objects/transform/) on the ZingChart site for date-time transformation. I'm on the ZingChart team. Holler if you have more questions.

Comment: Date time is working now, as I was doing some mistake in defining data series. Instead of defining series in scale-x and scale-y separately, I was defining them as one, that's why I was not getting the correct result.

Comment: I'm trying to display a milliseconds,amount csv using scale-x. That's what i get: https://i.imgur.com/pb3rRjZ.png. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Jofkos Please make a question with your chart JSON and a sample of the CSV you're using and I'll help you out